# How to show that inequality does not have integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have the following inequality:

$$\frac{(k-1) (n-1)}{k}-\frac{1}{k n-k}\leq x < \frac{(k-1) (n-1)}{k},$$

where  $(n|k|x) \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n \geq k \geq2$, $x>0$, and $n$ is an even number.

I have checked numerically and it seems that feasible solutions for $x$ given the constraints do not exist. How could one show it rigorously?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Since $n \geq 2$, $kn-k \geq k$. Show that $x$ can be bounded strictly between terms of the form $a/k, (a+1)/k$, so cannot be an integer.

Comment: Trying this out, thanks for a quick response!